# How do I turn this javascript into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am customising this [W3Schools tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_form_steps.asp). I would like to use jQuery to add animation to the transition between tabs. This is the relevant line in javascript function

```js
function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  x[n].style.display = "block";
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work.

```js
function showTab(n) {
  // This function will display the specified tab of the form ...
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  $("x[n]").show(750);
}
```

Comment: Remove the quotes from what you're passing to `$`

Comment: W3Schools love it when you confuse them with the W3C as it gives their terrible, advert-ridden site a veneer of respectability, but they aren't the W3C so I edited the question.

Comment: Note the the W3C and W3Schools are completely separate and unrelated entities. I would also suggest not using W3Schools at all. Their articles are often outdated and sometimes just plain wrong. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) and the jQuery [docs](https://api.jquery.com) are far more accurate and reliable.

Comment: Ah. I did confuse them. Point taken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide the value of `x[n]` to the jQuery constructor, not as a string literal:

```
$(x[n]).show(750);
```

That being said if you want to fully convert this to jQuery you can use a jQuery object and the `eq()` method to retrieve an element within it by index:

```js
function showTab(n) {
  $('.tab').eq(n).show(750);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently trying to get an element `<x n="something">`. Simply remove the quotes so it's not a selector but a jQuery object:

```
function showTab(n) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
  $(x[n]).show(750);
}
```